# "Npgsql.PostgresException" возникло в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll, 42703: столбец r.Active не существует

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка.

> Вызвано исключение: "Npgsql.PostgresException" в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
> Исключение типа "Npgsql.PostgresException" возникло в Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
> 42703: столбец r.Active не существует

У меня есть миграция , база создана , в ней есть все столбцы. Когда я делаю метод для добавления пользователя в базу у меня выходит данная ошибка (скриншот в конце).
Если что то ее потребуется для нахождения ошибки , то скажите пожалуйста , я предоставлю.
Также может быть есть совет как лучше делать такое.

Код репозитория:

```
 public User Add(SignupUser user)
        {
            var us  = new User();
         var viewUsername =   _dataBaseContext.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault( a => a.Username != user.User);
         var viewEmail = _dataBaseContext.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email != user.Email);


            us.Username = viewUsername.Username;
            us.Email = viewEmail.Email;
            us.Password = user.Password;
            us.Active = true;
            _dataBaseContext.Add<User>(us);
            return us; 
        }
```

модель , она создана в базе:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
        public String Username { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
        public String Password { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(500)")]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(16)")]
        public String Phone { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public Role[] Roles { get; set; }

    }
```

Скриншот:

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Дело было в регистре.  В модели были указаны с большой буквы , в базе с маленькой.

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в регистре. В модели были указаны с большой буквы , в базе с маленькой.